Graphic to fit in Cell Tabularray
I am trying to recreate this image, but I am having trouble with getting each logo to be similar size and take up the entire cell. I want the image to adjust to the cell size, and not the cell having to adjust to the size of the image.  See attached image.
Here is my Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amsfonts,tabularray,ragged2e,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand*{\Example}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(label.base)]
        \node at (0,0)[draw,fill=red,text=white](label){\textbf{#1}.{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{Center}
        \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,colspec={XXX[l]},rows={valign={h}}
        }
           \includegraphics[scale=.35]{BC LOGO.png}& \textbf{AP Calculus BC Notes}  & \textbf{Name:} \\
           
           \includegraphics[scale=.35]{FHMath.png}& {Created By: Nicholas Bennett \\ Flint Hill Upper School \\ nbennett@flinthill.org} &
            {\Example{2}{A} \textbf{Identify information} from multiple representations \\ \Example{3}{A}\textbf{Describe} the \textbf{characteristics} of a function}
        \end{tblr}
    \end{Center}
    
\end{document}



The box: tcolorbox. The ice cream cone picture: it's best to have the original (as a bitmap). The math symbol graphic: TikZ. Long story short: someone might create the whole thing for you completely.  Otherwise, I recommend breaking down the various tasks into individual questions.

As starting point (I didn't bother with coloring of cells because your MWE doesn't show any effort for this, I just show in few cell how to do this):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\Example}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(label.base)]
        \node at (0,0)[draw,fill=red,text=white](label){\textbf{#1}.{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{Center}
        \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,
                     colspec={QX[m]X[m]},
                     cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
                     cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{bg=yellow},
                     cell{3}{1} = {}{bg=yellow!30},
                     cell{3}{2} = {}{bg=yellow!60},
                     stretch=-1,
                     vspan=even, 
                     measure = vbox,
                    }
           \includegraphics[scale=.35,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
                & \textbf{AP Calculus BC Notes}  
                    & \textbf{Name:}                    \\
                & \textbf{Topic 1.2: Rates of changes}  
                    &                                   \\   
           
           \includegraphics[scale=.35,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
                & {Created By: Nicholas Bennett \\ Flint Hill Upper School \\ nbennett@flinthill.org} 
                    &   \begin{itemize}[nosep, itemsep=3pt]
                    \item[\Example{2}{A}]   \textbf{Identify information} from multiple representations 
                    \item[\Example{3}{A}]   \textbf{Describe} the \textbf{characteristics} of a function
                        \end{itemize}
        \end{tblr}
    \end{Center}   
\end{document}


Is this what you after?
Edit:
Regarding to your comment, that image occupy whole cell, is a bit harder. One way is to define height of image (by trial and error) so, that its height id bigger than text in adjacent cells. For example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\Example}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(label.base)]
        \node at (0,0)[draw,fill=red,text=white](label){\textbf{#1}.{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{Center}
        \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,
                     colspec={@{} Q[c] @{} X[m, leftsep=6pt]X[m]},  % removed tabcolsep in the first column
                                                                    % and added space tabcolsep at beginning second column
                     cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
                     cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{bg=yellow!30},
                     cell{3}{1} = {}{bg=yellow!30},
                     cell{3}{2} = {}{bg=yellow!60},
                     rowsep=0pt,  % <---added
                     stretch=-1,
                     vspan=even, 
                     measure = vbox,
                    }
           \includegraphics[height=22mm,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
                & \textbf{AP Calculus BC Notes}  
                    & \textbf{Name:}                    \\
                & \textbf{Topic 1.2: Rates of changes}  
                    &                                   \\   
           
           \includegraphics[height=22mm,,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
                & {Created By: Nicholas Bennett \\ Flint Hill Upper School \\ nbennett@flinthill.org} 
                    &   \begin{itemize}[nosep, itemsep=3pt]
                    \item[\Example{2}{A}]   \textbf{Identify information} from multiple representations 
                    \item[\Example{3}{A}]   \textbf{Describe} the \textbf{characteristics} of a function
                        \end{itemize}
        \end{tblr}
    \end{Center}   
\end{document}


Edit (2):
Your demand expressed in your comments can be achieved on the way as is shown in above example, when all images have the same size. If not, than narrower images will have horizontal gap before and after image. For example, If I cut-off images from your (deleted) answer and insert to above image, than the first image has mentioned gaps. This can be hided by coloring cells with color of image background (it it is uniform):
Edit (3):
A wee bit redesigned last example: added is ˙hyperreffor writing e-mail address and changed style forExample`. You my liked, if not use  own design of this table.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\Example}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(label.base)]
        \node at (0,0)[draw,fill=red,text=white](label){\textbf{#1}.{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{Center}
        \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,
                     colspec={@{} Q[c] @{} X[m, leftsep=6pt]X[m]},  % removed colsep in the first column
                                                                    % and added left space equal to colsep
                     cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{bg=NavyBlue!55!gray},       % colored gape before/after image
                     cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{bg=yellow!30},
                     cell{3}{1} = {}{bg=yellow!30},
                     cell{3}{2} = {}{bg=yellow!60},
                     rowsep=0pt,
                     stretch=-1,
                     vspan=even, 
                     measure = vbox,
                    }
           \includegraphics[height=23mm,valign=m]{Screenshot 2024-09-24 164651}
                & \textbf{AP Calculus BC Notes}  
                    & \textbf{Name:}                    \\
                & \textbf{Topic 1.2: Rates of changes}  
                    &                                   \\   
           
           \includegraphics[height=23mm,valign=m]{Screenshot 2024-09-24 164511}
                & {Created By: Nicholas Bennett \\ Flint Hill Upper School \\ nbennett@flinthill.org} 
                    &   \begin{itemize}[nosep, itemsep=3pt]
                    \item[\Example{2}{A}]   \textbf{Identify information} from multiple representations 
                    \item[\Example{3}{A}]   \textbf{Describe} the \textbf{characteristics} of a function
                        \end{itemize}
        \end{tblr}
    \end{Center}   
\end{document}

This approach keeps image aspect ratio:

However, if distortion in horizontal or vertical direction is acceptable to you, that you can tray the following solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{ragged2e}          % for Center environment 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\Example}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(label.base)]
        \node at (0,0)[fill=red,inner sep=2pt,text=white] (label) {\textbf{#1}.{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{Center}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=23mm, height=23mm}
        \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,
                     colspec={@{} Q[c] @{} X[0.9, m, leftsep=6pt]X[1.1, m]},  % removed colsep in the first column
                                                                    % and added left space equal to colsep
                     cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},       
                     cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{bg=yellow!30},
                     cell{3}{2} = {}{bg=yellow!60},
                     rowsep=0pt,
                     stretch=-1,
                     vspan=even, 
                     measure = vbox,
                    }
           \includegraphics[valign=m]{Screenshot 2024-09-24 164651}
                & \textbf{AP Calculus BC Notes}  
                    & \textbf{Name:}                    \\
                & \textbf{Topic 1.2: Rates of changes}  
                    &                                   \\   
           
           \includegraphics[valign=m]{Screenshot 2024-09-24 164511}
                & {Created by:\\ Nicholas Bennett \\ Flint Hill Upper School \\ \href{mailto: nbennett@flinthill.org}{nbennett@flinthill.org}}  
                    &   \begin{itemize}[nosep, itemsep=3pt]
                    \item[\Example{2}{A}]   \textbf{Identify information} from multiple representations 
                    \item[\Example{3}{A}]   \textbf{Describe} the \textbf{characteristics} of a function
                        \end{itemize}
        \end{tblr}
    \end{Center}   
\end{document}


Note: I cut-of image such, that they haven't any white border!

Looks awesome.  Is there a way for the images (ducks) to take up the entire cell?

This depend form images size and and height of text  in second and right columns. One way is to define height of images, which had to be bigger than text in adjacent cells. See edited answer.

@NickB, you may rethinking how to design \Example. I would remove border and reduce inner separation, Make it something like this \node at (0,0)[fill=red, inner sep=2pt, text=white](label){\textbf{#1}.{#2}};˛

you are the GOAT. Thank you for the help
